# MSP430 Simulation

Tags: msp430

I need to simulate encryption algorithms (AES 128/192/256, 3-DES, RC-6) to analyze performance in terms of execution time and memory usage of the MSP430F6749 microcontroller, searching I found some softwares like IAR Embedded Workbench , CCS and Proteus, but I have some doubts about that.

- Can I use ready codes on the internet and just do the performance measures ??? I already have these cryptography algorithms implemented in C, but the IAR Embedded Workbench (the only one I tried to use so far) does not allow the addition of external libraries, does anyone know how to do this in this software?
- It is possible to do the simulation in the CCS or I need a physical chip to be able to simulate?
- Can I use codes available on the internet or I should use a specific code for the MSP (I know that to work in a viable way the code must be optimized for MSP, but if I put a general code it will work too?).

Comment: I don't know what the actual question is, but when you care about the performance of computation-heavy code on a 16-bit microcontroller, the answer is guaranteed to be "no". (Except when you use a model that has a hardware accelerator buit in.)

Comment: Ok, I understood what you Said perfectly. MSP430F6749 has an AES 128 Accelerator Module. My doubt is: Can I implement another types of cryptographies in this MCU? What is the best and easiest  software to simulate that and acquire execution time and memory usage of the MCU during the execution. (I have all cryptographies algorithms in C language, but not optmized to the MCU, can I use these codes?)

Comment: I'm not sure about CCS, but you can use `mspsim`: https://github.com/contiki-ng/mspsim It has accurate timing. Only caveat is that it does not simulate the AES-128 hardware accelerator, so that code simply will not work.